# Laravel Check Login in resourse route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i'm using resource in route to send all request to controller. but in this route function i  use `'before' => 'csrf'` and user must login to view page, but if user not login i get this error :

```
ErrorException

Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/laravel/app/views/back_end/layouts/profile.blade.php)
```

for this line into profile.blade.php:

```
Auth::user()->username;
```

my define route is below code :

```
Route::get('login', array('as'=>'login', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.login');
}));
Route::resource('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController' , array('as'=>'profile' , 'before'=>'csrf'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

Setup Authentication Filter at filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

Then on routes.php

```
Route::get('login', array('as'=>'login', function()
{
    return View::make('back_end.login');
}));

//Group to put all the routes that need login first
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
  Route::resource('admin/profile' , 'ProfileController' , array('as'=>'profile' , 'before'=>'csrf'));
});
```